# Unity callback on AudioSource played

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, audio

Is there any callbacks when an `AudioSource` is played?

I'm using `AudioSource.PlayScheduled()` because my game requires high precision on audio playing timing.
But I can't find any callbacks when scheduled `AudioSource` is playing.

And this is what I am intending to do.

```cs
double delayTime = ...;
Audiosource src;

src.PlayScheduled(AudioSettings.dspTime + delayTime);
src.OnPlay += ...;
```

Comment: There are no callbacks. Your best bet would probably be to just check `IsPlaying` on each update, though that likely lacks the precision you are hoping for. I've seen this question a couple times but there isn't a great answer unfortunately, short of rolling your own AudioSource implementation.

Comment: Or maybe create your own logic by inheriting from `AudioSource`

Comment: @loic.lopez Unity chose to seal the `AudioSource` class.